# Cannot recieve the values from JSON-string by angular.js

Tags: angularjs, json, jsp, spring-boot

I have tried to implement some methods from a tutorial [javasampleapproach.com/spring-framework/spring-boot/spring-jpa-postgresql-angularjs-example-spring-boot](http://javasampleapproach.com/spring-framework/spring-boot/spring-jpa-postgresql-angularjs-example-spring-boot) but it doesn't work for me.

When I hit the GET ALL CUSTOMERS-button nothing comes up. When I tried to add a testmessage with the json-text that I have requested from the RestController and just use @scope.allPersons.data the complete json-text come up but if I try to get the valuesin the json-responese it is either undefined or nothing comes up.

First of all, the RestController. I have tried with `@RequestMapping(value="/findallresponse", produces = "application/json")`and the default from the tutorial as showed in the code. The reason for making my own String Json is that if I responded with the Iteratable-object the response get recursive because of @ManyToMany-relation. And when I troubleshoot I left out the Hobbypart because that was the ManyToMany-relationship value.

```
@RequestMapping("/findallresponse")
public Response findAllResponse(){  
    ArrayList firstNameStr=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList lastNameStr=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList hobbyStr=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList idStr=new ArrayList<String>();
    boolean startLoop=true;
    String jsonPersonBeggining="{\"persons\":[";
    String jsonPersonEnd="]}";
    String jsonPerson="";
    for(Person person : personService.findAll()){
        if(startLoop==true)
        {
            startLoop=false;
        }
        else
        {
            jsonPerson+=",";
        }
        jsonPerson+="{";

        jsonPerson+="\"firstName\":\""+person.getFirstName()+"\",";
        jsonPerson+="\"lastName\":\""+person.getLastName()+"\",";
        //jsonPerson+="\"hobby\":\""+person.getHobby()+"\",";
        jsonPerson+="\"id\":\""+person.getId()+"\"";



        jsonPerson+="}";
    }

    jsonPerson=jsonPersonBeggining+jsonPerson+jsonPersonEnd;


    return new Response("Done",jsonPerson);
}
```

Here is the Response-class just as in the tutorial

```
public class Response {
    private String status;
    private Object data;

    public Response() {

    }

    public Response(String status, String data) {
        this.status = status;
        this.data = data;

    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public Object getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

The javascript-file as in the tutorial. The @getResultMessage is to test that the json-string is recieved at all. And it is. But after that I can't access the post in it, for instance

> `firstName` or 
>   `lastName`

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('getallpersonsController', function($scope, $http, $location) 
{
    $scope.showAllPersons = false;
    $scope.getAllPersons = function() {
        var url = $location.absUrl() + "findallresponse";

        var config = {
            headers : {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json;charset=utf-8;'
            }
        }

        $http.get(url, config).then(function(response) {

            if (response.data.status == "Done") {
                $scope.allpersons = response.data;
                $scope.showAllPersons = true;
                $scope.getResultMessage = $scope.allpersons.data;

            } else {
                $scope.getResultMessage = "get All Customers Data Error!";
            }

        }, function(response) {
            $scope.getResultMessage = "Fail!";
        });
    }
});
```

This is the output on this is the @getResultMessage taken from @scope.allpersons.data

> {"persons":[{"firstName":"Adam","lastName":"Johnson","id":"87"},{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Persson","id":"90"},{"firstName":"Nils","lastName":"Svensson","id":"93"}]}

And the jsp-file

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<title>Spring Boot Example</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<script
  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.min.js">
</script>
<script src="/js/angular.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" ng-app="app">
        <h1>AngularJS - Spring JPA - PostgreSQL</h1>

        <div class="row">
            <div ng-controller="getallpersonsController" class="col-md-3">
                <h3>All Customers</h3>

                <button ng-click="getAllPersons()">
                    Get All Customers
                </button>

                <div ng-show="showAllPersons">
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li ng-repeat="persons in allpersons.data">
                            <h4 class="list-group-item">
                                <strong>Customer {{$index}}</strong><br />
                                Id: {{persons.id}}<br />
                                First Name: {{persons.firstName}}<br />
                                Last Name: {{persons.lastName}}
                            </h4>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <p>{{getResultMessage}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE!!

Here is some calls on the response if that can give any clue?

> data=[object Object] status=200 
>   statustext=undefined 
>   headers=function (d){b||(b=od(a));return d?(d=b[L(d)],void 0===d&&(d=null),d):b} config=[object Object]

Can anyone see if I missed something? In the jsp-file the ng-repeatloop is not working, it doesn't seems to be able to get the value from the json? Thanks

Comment: Might be a scoping issue, have you thought about using controller as syntax?  https://www.codementor.io/cnorthfield/why-you-should-use-angularjs-s-controller-as-syntax-6i001lr5p

Comment: I recieve the response  as a string. The problem is to make it work as a jsonarray

Comment: have you tried to update

    String jsonPersonBeggining="{\"persons\":[";
    String jsonPersonEnd="]}";

to

    String jsonPersonBeggining="[{\"persons\":[";
    String jsonPersonEnd="]}]";

?

Comment: which wraps response in square brackets

Comment: I solved it by passing it as a string instead of a resourseobject. I dont know what with the resourse was not working.